# Convergence of $a_k=\sum_{k=5}^{+\infty}(-1)^k({3\over2})^{-k}(k^2+5)\sin(k+5)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, absolute-convergence

Firstly, $\lim_{k \to +\infty}a_k=0$,so necessary condition for convergence is satisfied.If we start to study absolute convergence we have : $$a_k=({3\over2})^{-k}(k^2+5)|\sin(k+5)|\leq({3\over2})^{-k}(k^2+5)\sim({3\over2})^{-k}(k^2)=\frac{k^2}{({3\over2})^{k}}$$
So if we apply ratio test : $$\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{(k+1)^2({3\over2})^k}{({3\over2})^k({3\over2})(k^2)}={2\over3}\lt1$$  And $a_k$ is absolutely and simply convergent.Is this approach correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You could have used plain comparison, since $\sin(k+5)$ is bounded and $(3/2)^{-k}$ goes to zero faster than, say, $k^{-4}$.

Comment: @GReyes what exactly our comparison function would look like?Probably ${k^2\over k^4}={1\over k^2}$?

Comment: I think your sum does converge.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it does,for sure.

Comment: @TuranNəsibli Yes, you are right. For large enough $k$, $(3/2)^{-k}\le k^{-4}$ and $\sin(k+5)\le 1$, therefore your $|a_k|\le 1/k^2$.